# Regular Expressions to get matched result

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Am unaware of Regular expressions and am using jquery ui auto-complete and filling a textbox in my site. I need to change the result of normal jquery ui autocomplete like below.

**For example**

```
Chennai, Chengalpattu, Chettinadu, tiruchendur, Calcutta, Mumbai, Hyderabad, Bhopal
```

If I type **che**, I need the results as

```
Chennai, Chengalpattu, Chettinadu, tiruchendur
```

It is normally coming good in jquery ui autocomplete but If we type **chegkkj** also it should show

```
Chennai, Chengalpattu, Chettinadu, tiruchendur
```

this result ignoring contents typed after possible matched results. Is it possible, I choosed Regular expression but completely unaware of it or else is there any other possible ways to achieve it?

**Fiddle == > [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9McSk/)**

Comment: Fiddle would be convenient !

Comment: For instant example you can view [this](http://www.redbus.in/) site. I will prepare fiddle shortly.

Comment: So based on what I can tell, you want it to understand that `che` should be valid to search by. But what if they type in chekkj, why wouldn't it be valid to find all items that contain a `c`. I don't think what you are looking for is possible with a single RegEx.

Comment: Nothing to do with regular expressions. You mean a "did you mean?"-like function which uses some kind of string distance algorithm. You will find plenty of docs on wikipedia (ie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: I added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9McSk/) too.

Comment: @Guts From looking at your fiddle I believe you are misunderstanding how the auto-complete works, it uses the entire string entered by the user to find matches, not parts of the string. To find matches for parts of the string you will have to develop your own custom function for this.

Comment: Is it possible to get the result shown by jquery ui autocomplete, that we can store it in a variable and if no match found we can pass stored variable as response for it?